# Replace NA with average of the case before and after the NA

Tags: r, replace, average, na

Say I have the following data.frame:

```
t<-c(1,1,2,4,5,4)
u<-c(1,3,4,5,4,2)
v<-c(2,3,4,5,NA,2)
w<-c(NA,3,4,5,2,3)
x<-c(2,3,4,5,6,NA)

df<-data.frame(t,u,v,w,x)
```

I would like to replace the NAs with values that represent the average of the case before and after the NA, unless a row starts (row 4) or ends (row 5) with an NA. When the row begins with NA, I would like to substitute the NA with the following case. When the row ends with NA, I would like to substitute the NA with the previous case.

Thus, I would like my output to look like:

```
t<-c(1,1,2,4,5,4)
u<-c(1,3,4,5,4,2)
v<-c(2,3,4,5,3.5,2)
w<-c(3,3,4,5,2,3)
x<-c(2,3,4,5,6,6)

df<-data.frame(t,u,v,w,x)
```

Comment: Instead of putting your output in a comment, please just edit your question.

Comment: Try looking at `?na.aggregate` from `zoo`

Comment: what do you mean by following case and previous case?

Comment: Select the data and press control k. That will indent it 4 spaces in which case SO will format it properly.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! @Mike: I meant the value before the NA and after the NA in the samen row. Thus, I haven't found the correct option yet. Sorry for being unclear. @G: Thanks for the help with intending!

Comment: @DavidMaij that makes sense; for some reason I thought you might have been referring to the sets on either side of NA (average of averages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question refers to row 4 starting with NA and row 5 ending in NA but in fact column 4 of the input `df` starts with an NA and column 5 of the input ends with an NA and neither row 4 nor row 5 of the input start or end with an NA so we will assume that column was meant, not row.  Also there are two data frames both named `df` in the question. Evidently one is supposed to represent the input and the other data frame having the same name is the output but for complete clarity we have repeated the definition of the `df` we have used in the Note at the end.

`na.approx` in zoo pretty much does this.  (If a matrix result is OK then omit the `data.frame()` part.)

```
library(zoo)

data.frame(na.approx(df, rule = 2))
```

giving:

```
  t u   v w x
1 1 1 2.0 3 2
2 1 3 3.0 3 3
3 2 4 4.0 4 4
4 4 5 5.0 5 5
5 5 4 3.5 2 6
6 4 2 2.0 3 6
```

**Note:** For clarity, we used this data frame as input above:

```
df <- structure(list(t = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4), u = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 
2), v = c(2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 2), w = c(NA, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3), x = c(2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, NA)), .Names = c("t", "u", "v", "w", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(df, function(x){
    replace(x, is.na(x), rowMeans(cbind(c(NA, head(x, -1)), c(x[-1], NA)), na.rm = TRUE)[is.na(x)])
})
#     t u   v w x
#[1,] 1 1 2.0 3 2
#[2,] 1 3 3.0 3 3
#[3,] 2 4 4.0 4 4
#[4,] 4 5 5.0 5 5
#[5,] 5 4 3.5 2 6
#[6,] 4 2 2.0 3 6
```